# How to include multiple color styles with a conditional statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to optimize a script that targets multiple rgb color styles. It looks like this:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[style^="color"]');
[].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
    if(div.style.color.includes('rgb(215, 218, 220)')){
        div.style.color="rgb(23, 23, 24)";
    }
});
```

I'd like to do the same thing which is done for target style `rgb(215, 218, 220)`, for `255, 69, 0` and `113, 147, 255`. How would that be accomplished most simply and efficiently?

Comment: You mean you want to do the same thing which is done for target style `rgb(215, 218, 220)`, also for `255, 69, 0 and 113, 147, 255` them ?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to substitute all three instances of these colors for `23, 23, 24`.

Comment: If you're able to modify the pages where this script applies, you'd better use CSS "Variables" (Custom Properties). If it's more like a Webextension, of course my comment is void :)

Comment: I'm trying to get around Reddit's nonsense class names with a user script. This is the only approach that seems to work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely to be inefficient as it reads and write dom according to a string match but you could use [RegExp.prototype.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/test) instead of String.prototype.includes:

```
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[style^="color"]');
    var regexp = /rgb\(215, 218, 220\)|rgb\(255, 69, 0\)|rgb\(113, 147, 255\)/;
    [].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
        if(regexp.test(div.style.color)){
            div.style.color="rgb(23, 23, 24)";
        }
    });
```